# Problem with local Azure deployment

Tags: azure

I'm trying to run a WebRole on my local machine via Compute Emulator. My Compute Emulator and Storage Emulator is running fine. When I hit F5 in VS2010, I can see the action in Compute Emulator. But after a while, I get an exception in VS2010;

```
  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.RuntimeEnvironmentException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to load the runtime environment: could not get hosting environment settings
  Source=WaWorkerHost
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Parameters..ctor()
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Loader.Main(String[] args)
  InnerException:
```

Then Roles in Compute Emulator begins to shutdown. VS2010 launches the browser with IP and port but no luck, it's not running of course.

I don't think this is a coding error because I live the same problem even in an empty out-of-the-box Azure project and a single Web Role on it.

I've searched the net but no info about this error. Actually if you search exactly for "RuntimeEnvironmentException" Google returns zero result. Using the description words also does not make any sense.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: Does this only happen on your machine?

Comment: This error, yes! Honestly I've not managed to run "any" Azure projects locally on any of my machines. But this error is on this machine only. BTW, when I uncomment "Sites" node in ServiceDefinition file, VS2010 does not throw an error. But WebRole in compute emulator immediately becomes "Unhealty" and stucks in that way. In event viewer I see this error:

Comment: Faulting application name: WaIISHost.exe, version: 6.0.6002.18009, time stamp: 0x4d6ac6d2
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17625, time stamp: 0x4de88429
Exception code: 0xe0434352

Comment: Which version of the SDK and tools? (New tools shipped earlier this week.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for not responding earlier but I was still working on the issue. Then a Microsoft guy from Turkey office figured it out. There is a problem with localization on developer machines. In development environment computers, in "Region and Languages", set "Format" to "English (United States)" and "Current Location" to "United States". After setting these, Azure emulator is working flawlessly. They said this is a known issue and they're preparing a report about this. I hope this will be resolved in next releases.

Hope this helps to anyone who live same problem. And thanks everyone who tried to help...

Ali

Comment: And here is the Microsoft KB about this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2589199 . It seems only computers with Turkish locale are affected...

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue where the compute emulator just fails to load my web role and nothing ever responds.  It seems to happen to me when I hibernate my laptop a few times while the compute emulator is running.  Even shutting the emulator down and restarting it doesn't seem to help.

Best solution I've found is to reboot.  Definitely not elegant (and a bit of a pain in the butt), but it's worked for me every time.

Not sure if this helps or not.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I've rebooted several times with no luck. Prior to my response, I've tested once again but nothing changed. Everything is same...

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Restart helped to sort it out.